# Read a text file with readr where a quote ends rows

Tags: r, readr

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
a,b,c,d
"string1","string2","string3","
"string4","string5","string6","
```

The file itself is comma separated, but each line ends with a double quote (i.e., not the comma delimiter). `readr::read_delim()` does not understand the line endings and thus tries to read all data into a single line.

`data.table::fread()` imports as expected, but I'd like to find a `readr` solution, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fread` seems by far the easiest option in this case. If you don't want `fread` to return a `data.table`, you can use the `data.table = FALSE` parameter in `fread`.

An example:

```
fread("C:/data.txt", data.table = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm not opposed to data.table, but was curious whether I had missed something obvious in the `readr` package documentation. Line endings are detected automatically in `data.table`, which does not seem to be the case with `readr`.

Comment: @Chris As far as I can see (and I've looked extensively) you didn't miss anything in the documentation of `readr`. I guess the `readr`-functions are less flexible than `fread`, which has its advantages and disadvantages (like in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one long-winded approach, but surely there is a more parsimonious solution:

```
readr::read_lines("C:/data.txt", skip = 1) %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
  tidyr::separate(value, into = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(a:c), 
            .funs = stringr::str_replace_all, 
            pattern = "\"", 
            replacement = "")
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to avoid using `fread`. If you don't want to use it because `fread` returns a `data.table`, see my answer for a solution.

Comment: In cases where my data include delimiters or other "reserved" characters, I've moved away from read.csv and gravitated to readXL to avoid mis-specification during the import process. Perhaps consider a different data storage option?

Comment: I agree it's a lot of code. Using `data.table` works and is much more parsimonious, but was hopeful I missed something in `readr`.